# replace headings in a word document

Tags: replace, ms-word

I am looking for a macro or way to replace all headings in a word document with one numeric value so that every heading at every level gets replaced with same numeric value.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It came out to be easy.

Use { SEQ heading } field. Copy the field code, select the destination format in Find and use ^c^p in replace. All headings with selected style will get the numeric value. Do the same for rest.